# SQL - JOIN only newest log entry for id

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm currently writing a calendar application which supports switching statusses for days.

The First Table I got is currently like this:

```
days:
|---|-------|----------|------|
|uid|day_id |date      |status|
|1  |1024   |2021-01-01|0     |
|1  |1025   |2021-01-02|0     |
|1  |1026   |2021-02-24|0     |
and so on...
```

Everytime a Super User (a user above the user, in this example with user id 0) accepts a day, the `status` column gets changed and gets an entry into the table log, which after a while could look like this:

```
log:
|------|------|----------|----------|
|day_id|status|changed_by|timestamp |
|1024  |1     |0         |1619510887|
|1024  |3     |0         |1629510187|
|1024  |2     |0         |1619593687|
|1025  |1     |0         |1619510887|
|1025  |2     |0         |1629510187|
|1026  |2     |0         |1619593687|
and so on...
```

Now I'd like to select a day by the days.uid and join it with the **newest** entry from the log table.

How can I do this in the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM days d
JOIN (SELECT * FROM log WHERE d.day_id=? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) l
    ON l.day_id = d.day_id
WHERE d.uid=? AND d.day_id=?
```

Comment: oh man, you made me realize a made a big mistake in my question... sorry